# Why do parentheses as a python argument cause a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, syntax-error

When following a python2 tutorial, it often defines functions like this:

```
def scale(self, (centre_x, centre_y), scale):
```

which throws a SyntaxError in python3, highlighting the parenthesis in front of "centre_x". I also notice that you cannot use parentheses to group, say like this:

```
def test(x, (y + 1)):
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `(y + 1)` doesn't make any sense as an argument name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a supported syntax in Python 2.x but it was removed in Python 3.0.

See [*PEP 3113 – Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking*](https://peps.python.org/pep-3113/) for detail.